# How to pass cert and key using h2load

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, tls1.2

I've been trying to run an h2load test on an endpoint.
when executing a curl command it works well, here is an example:

curl --insecure -X POST https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:18093/endpoint --cacert myCaCrtFile.crt --cert myCertFile.crt --key myKey.key -d ./data.json

but I haven't find a way to pass my cert, cacert and key through h2load, any suggestions?